# ajax doesn't execute or receive external scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, content-security-policy

This is a follow up to my previous [question (unresolved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881311/allow-insert-file-js-by-getscript-in-content-security-policy-csp).

Directives in .htaccess:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'; style-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-22os9h3sdfa'; connect-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; child-src 'none'; report-uri https://mydomain.info/csp-reporting.php"
```

CSP Log -> report.txt file from my domain: **[Link](https://horbaczewski.info/csp/report_2017-02-07.txt)**
*remove /csp/report_2017-02-07.txt from Link then you get link to my own site*

I try load external script via ajax get metod:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'script',
         headers: {
            Accept : 'text/javascript; charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Type': 'text/javascript; charset=utf-8'
        },
        url: 'https://mydomain.info/js/library.js',/*I change url for fake on public share. My correct url is in above link*/
        /*data: { nonce: '22os9h3sdfa' }, - use attrs solution from: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3028*/
        attrs: { nonce: '22os9h3sdfa' },
        cache : true,
        jsonp: false,
        async: true,
        success: function() { console.log('xhr was send'); },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, status, errorThrown) {
            if (status == 'Unauthorized') { console.log(' === Error: ' + errorThrown + ' === '); }
            else { console.log(' === Error: ' + errorThrown + ' === '); }
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR.status);
            console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    })
```

I spent a lot of time finding the error & what blocks the script execution..
Need help, please..

Comment: I get only string from request after send header so I should use pharser to execute script. I change my code on something else solution. I don't recommended above code to use with CSP. When CSP level 3 will be stable then 'use strict-dynamic' then it will be work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have different stuff here that cause errors:

- first, a bunch of your first CSP errors coming up come from styles that are declared "inline" (with attribute `style=` directly in the html tags). To allow this, you have to declare it like this:

  `style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';`
- following the same scheme, the CSP will disallow all inline javascript too, that maybe doesn't come from you, but can be in the librairies (never declared a nonce as a source, but i trust your word on that, no time to search right now):

  `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'nonce-22os9h3sdfa';`
- you seem to load external images, while it is not declared in the CSP, try adding them (you can be more restrictive on the path, the * here allows you to access all sub-domains of the specified domain):

  `img-src 'self' 'https://*.amazonaws.com';`
- at last, your main problem seems to be the loading of the resources itself, maybe their order or what, but your loading sequence is not stable. Most of the time it will actually load the lib file, but the rest of the time i have a jquery undefined error (ReferenceError: $ is not defined). When the lib loads, an element is not defined when it is called (jQuery.Deferred exception: Swiper is not defined @index.js:380:4). Maybe you could try to move your jQuery inclusion to the `head`, or maybe declare the no conflict like this (i never saw it done the way you do it before, dunno if it is legit):

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
      //the call of jQuery.noConflict(); makes the global $ var undefined, and returns the jQuery instance
  ```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ad4. ok, I remove 'jQuery.noConflict();' and still work :) 'jQuery.noConflict();' was use for work jquery code only.
AD1. Yes I have some errors with style but that doesn't stop script.
Ad2. I cant use 'unsafe-inline' when I have 'nonce-22os9h3sdfa', error: "Content Security Policy: Ignoring „'unsafe-inline'” in script-src or style-src: specified „nonce-source” or „hash-source”"
Ad3. Great Idea! :)
So your solution in Ad2. don't work :(

Comment: never declared a nonce as a source in CSP, so i can't really help here, but if you don't find a way, you can still try to remove the inline JS so you can go without 'unsafe-inline' (which is a good idea anyway), hoping it's not inside a cryptic library.. gook luck ;)

Comment: I found info that nounce can be use like as source: [link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#reporting)
_CSP Level 2 offers backward compatibility for inline scripts by allowing you to whitelist specific inline scripts using either a cryptographic nonce (number used once) or a hash. Although this may be cumbersome in practice, it is useful in a pinch.(..)_